# When sending from react native tcp client to a node js tcp server, the first message is sent successfully the second throws error

Tags: android, react-native, tcp

[image]

Im using react-native-tcp-socket and my code is identical to what is in their docs.  I am able to make a connection and send/receive one message, but when I try to connect again, I get this error.  I am working on an android simulator and connecting to a node js server.

```
var client = TcpSocket.createConnection(options);

client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('message was received', data);
});

client.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

client.on('close', function(){
  console.log('Connection closed!');
});

// Write on the socket
client.write('COORDINATE_MOVE ELEV:' + this.state.elevation + 'AZIM:' + this.state.azimuth + 'ID:todd');

// Close socket
client.destroy();
```

Comment: You can't reconnect a TCP socket. You have to close it and create a new one.

Comment: isn't that what the client.destroy does?

Comment: I have no idea, but the error message suggests you are reusing the same object rather than creating a new one.

Comment: bingo, I was setting 'options' in a way that the hostname was a constant.. thank you